# The Hermicity of k.p Hamiltonian with operator ordering?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I am trying to use the  k.p method to study quantum well band structure. One example Hamiltonian look like this [J. Appl. Phys., 116, 033709(2014)]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrw3r.png)

where 
${{\hat k}_ \pm } = {{\hat k}_x} \pm i{{\hat k}_y}$
and the matrix elements are function of ${{\hat k}_i}$

and if quantum well is grown along z direction
$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{{\hat k}_x} =  - i\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}} \to {k_x}\\
{{\hat k}_y} =  - i\frac{\partial }{{\partial y}} \to {k_y}\\
{{\hat k}_z} =  - i\frac{\partial }{{\partial z}}
\end{array} \right.$

this Hamiltonian is an hermitian operator, but I am confused about this. For example, if we look at the (1,4) and (4,1) terms and use ${{\hat k}_z}=-i{\partial _z}$, the (1,4) term becomes 
  $-i{\partial _z}{P_1}$
and the (4,1) term becomes 
$- i{P_1}{\partial _z}$

If I use finite difference method to turn these two terms into a matrix block, the factor -i is not going to  flip sign and the matrix cannot he a hermitian matrix?

there must be something wrong with my understanding, please help.